# Flutter local notification to execute code before showing itself

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

In flutter application I want to show local notification with progress of some task.
Progress of the task is stored locally (`shared_preferences` or `sqflite`).

Is it possible in flutter to schedule a local notification to be shown (executed) exactly at midnight but before showing itself, to execute some code? So it can read actual progress of the task and display proper message in the notification, e.g. "Task completed in X%".

It would be much easier to read current progress, rather than cancel existing local notification, and add new one, every time task is progressed a bit.

In other words - can local notification:

- be called silently?
- execute code when delivered?

I am using `flutter_local_notifications` but there is no way to execute code when push notification is about to show.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? Currently I am trying to detect, when a notification was shown, to play a custom sound

Comment: @Sebb I didn't. Seems like this functionality doesn't exists (yet?).

Comment: Ah, too bad, that's what I thought. Thanks for the answer anyway.